# Consequences on Flutter unit testing requiring all model objects to extend equatable

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, model, pojo

When testing for object data equality, models need to override both operator==() & hashCode(), and possibly be immutable if equatable was used.

What would be the consequences in general in term of memory optimization & instantiation time?
Should I consider the idea of creating separate models for testing, leaving the real models intact?

Currently I'm overriding the operator==() & hashCode() methods when needed for every real model.
But I fear this will leave a negative impact on the app performance.

Please share your experience with unit testing in Dart/Flutter.